# String split in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table that contains a list of pagehits that I would like to analyse. One of the fields is `URL` that unsurprisingly contains the URL of the pagehit. This includes any query strings, e.g. `http://foo.bar/default.aspx?test=1234`

I would like to strip out the query strings from this table for my analysis and thought the following simple string split would work:

```
    var pageHits = from p in context.Pagehits
                   let URL = p.URL.Split('?')[0]
                   select p;
```

However I get the error:
`The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`

Given the table is fairly hefty whats the best way to return the URL without the query strings?

EDIT:
I can get it work if i call `.ToList` but that seems computationally excessive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
              var pageHits = from p in list
                             select p.Substring(0,p.IndexOf('?');
```

I made a List of strings which contains urls only to check if it works (my "list" in the code)

Answer (score -2):

```
               var pageHits = from p in context.Pagehits
               select p;

               pageHits.ToList().ForEach(p => 
                                   { 
                                     p.Url = p.Url.Split('?')[0];
                                   });
```